# How to convert CSV data into graph dataset for anomaly detection?

Tags: graph, pytorch, anomaly-detection

I am working on an anomaly detection problem using a graph neural network. However, I am not sure which will be the best way to convert my CSV data into graph data. I have 115 different attributes for each timestamp. You can find the example dataset here; https://gist.github.com/vgthengane/0b20f1b018b7ea06799f3ae00e167a7c

I want to test each time stamp for an anomaly. Which will be the best way to convert CSV data into graph data?

I was thinking of considering each attribute as a node and connecting all of them with each other by the undirected edge (since I don't know their connection to each other). Then I will have a single feature for each node and a lot of edges. To be specific `feature_shape == [115, 1]` and `edge_shape == [2, 6555]`. But I am not sure if this is a good way to model it, and what will be the best method to work on this on node embedding or graph embedding?

PS: I am using an autoencoder model to detect anomalies.

Hope I am clear about my question.

Comment: What is your definition of anomaly?  What do you want to happen when an 'anomaly' is 'detected'

Comment: I have a time-series dataset. where each timestamp has 115 feature values. The dataset consists of a normal and anomaly (A sample that is deviated from the normal sample) samples. I want to convert this CSV data in such away that I can apply to GNN and detect anomalies.

Comment: Why do you want to use graphs here? What is the graph-like nature that you wish to represent?

Comment: Your definition defines nothing.  Saying an anomaly is a deviation get us no further forward.  You need to say something like "when the values is more than 2 standard deviations from the mean of the previous 100 samples"